# Magento 2 add maxlength in form ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, form-validation, ui-form

I know magento give `max_text_length` validation for validating length & print error message regarding it, but I want to add attribute in my input field as `maxlength="5"` so i can stop user to adding more value from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below line in your:

```
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/form/element/input</item>
<item name="maxlength" xsi:type="number">5</item> <!-- it's a variable which is used on template side for getting values from it-->
```

add **VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/input.html**

```
               <input class="admin__control-text" type="text"
data-bind="
    event: {change: userChanges},
    value: value,
    hasFocus: focused,
    valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled,
        maxlength: maxlength // here we assign dynamic value '5' from maxlength var
}"/>
```

after adding please run below commands:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>   php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this answer is not fulfilling the current scenario.

Comment: why May i know? @Himanshu

Comment: it's change all input as above added configuration.

Comment: @Himanshu i have edited my answer please apply it. it will work for perticular input field

Comment: @Himanshu have you tried?

Comment: Hi @Rutvee is there any way to pass dynamic value in maxlength ?

Comment: I have updated the answer for getting dynamic values for max-length. so it will be reusable.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, can you please tell me how to add maxlength in add new address form in checkout process,as far you answer is matching but not working perfectly

Comment: @RutveeSojitra,this file VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/input.html works fine no need to add extra code